# How to get tag of user in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

If I have the user object, how would I get the tag of the user? For example, if I wanted to print something like `CircuitSacul#1111`, I would use something like

```py
print(f"{owner.name}:#{owner.tag}")
```

However, I get the error that "User object has no attribute 'tag'".

Comment: Note that printing the `User`/`Member` object would achieve the same result.

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine Yes thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [user's discriminator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.discriminator):

```
@bot.command()
async def tag(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.discriminator)
```